# Composing a complex query in SQLAlchemy expression language

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

## What I got so far

I have two fairly simple querys that kind of look like this in SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(known), item FROM log  GROUP BY item
SELECT COUNT(known), item FROM (SELECT known, item FROM log WHERE known == 1) GROUP BY item
```

With a table "log" that has columns "known", "item", both querys do count rows, one how many rows for each item is in a table, the other one how many rows for each item is in a table with the field "known" set to 1. This is how far I got with SQLite directly and I was also able to translate it to an SQLAlchemy expression.

## Aim

I would like to do something which could be  a little complicated. I would like to write the results of both queries into another table, possibly overwriting entries there. Schema looks a little bit like this.

```
CREATE TABLE fractions (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    item INTEGER, 
    sum_known_only FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    sum FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY(item) REFERENCES items (id), 
)
```

- How can I get the values into this table?
- Is this solvable with a single SQL Expression? I would like to try to avoid fetching the values from the database and then putting them in again
- How can I phrase such a complex expression with sqlalchemy expression language?
- The bonus would be: Can I use subqueries to build fractions of `sum` and `sum_known_only` for each `item`?

I appreciate both SQLAlchemy expression language (not ORM) and general SQL hints, both will be very helpful to me.

Comment: How do `COUNT(known)` in your first sample `SQL` queries correspond to `sum` and `sum_known_only` in the `fractions` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that I assumed (because the field is `FLOAT`) that there is a `Log.value` column with the value that you are actually summing, and not just doing simple counting (which is going to be even more simple).

Query below should allow you to select both values in one query, and the rest of the answer will be using it:

```
one_select = (
    session
    .query(
        Log.item.label("item"),
        # func.count(Log.item).label("num_all"),
        # func.sum(case([(Log.known == 1, 1)], 0)).label("num_known"),
        func.sum(Log.value).label("sum_all"),
        func.sum(case([(Log.known == 1, Log.value)], 0)).label("sum_known_only")
    )
    .group_by(Log.item)
)
```

Inserting new records is quite simple, but in order to make a full update, we need also to delete existing records first, therefore the function below:

```
def delete_insert():
    """
    First delete from Fraction table, then insert *all* values.
     + rather simple
     - probably not the most efficient for the large table
    """
    session.flush()

    # 1. first delete existing ones
    subq = exists(
        select([1]).where(Log.item == Fraction.item).correlate(Fraction))
    de_ = delete(Fraction).where(subq)
    session.execute(de_)

    # 2. now insert all
    ins = (insert(Fraction).from_select(
        (Fraction.item, Fraction.sum, Fraction.sum_known_only), one_select))
    session.execute(ins)

    session.commit()
```

One can also create `update_insert` version of it, where first we update values for existing `Fraction` records, and then insert new ones. But update is a bit more involved, although happy to provide it as well, if you specify your database engine and what you mean with *build fractions*.